# Node-nlp Bayes Classifier got a very low score

Tags: javascript, nlp

I just follow it according to this https://github.com/axa-group/nlp.js/issues/126#issuecomment-444852649

but I got a very low score different from what was exemplified. https://runkit.com/jesus-seijas-sp/5c0910e71539810012150767

is there some kind of rule that I miss?

I just want to use BayesClassifier

Iam using : `"node-nlp": "^2.4.2"`

```
const { BayesClassifier, NlpManager } = require('node-nlp');

    async function main() {
        const bayes = new BayesClassifier();
        const manager = new NlpManager({
          languages: ['en'],
          classifier: bayes,
          useNeural: false,
        });
        manager.addDocument('en', 'Hello', 'greet');
        manager.addDocument('en', 'Good evening', 'greet');
        manager.addDocument('en', 'Good morning', 'greet');
        manager.addDocument('en', "I've lost my keys", 'keys');
        manager.addDocument('en', "I don't find my keys", 'keys');
        manager.addDocument('en', "I don't know where are my keys", 'keys');
        await manager.train();
        const result = await manager.process('Where are my keys');
        console.log(result);
    }

    main();
```

**RESULT**

```
{ locale: 'en',
  localeIso2: 'en',
  language: 'English',
  utterance: 'Where are my keys',
  classification:
   [ { label: 'keys', value: 0.055555555555555546 },
     { label: 'greet', value: 0.006172839506172837 } ],
  intent: 'keys',
  domain: 'default',
  score: 0.055555555555555546,
  entities: [],
  sentiment:
   { score: 0,
     comparative: 0,
     vote: 'neutral',
     numWords: 4,
     numHits: 0,
     type: 'senticon',
     language: 'en' } }
```

Comment: I've just run this, and I get the same scores as you 0.05-ish rather than 0.98-ish. I'll look into it further. They're using v2.3.0.

Answer (score 0):

the developer here!
There was a breaking change between 2.3.x and 2.4.x
At 2.3.x a normalization was done for every classification, the code for this normalization is here: 
https://github.com/axa-group/nlp.js/blob/master/lib/nlp/nlp-classifier.js#L241

At 2.4.x this normalization is done only when the results came from a brain.js neural network, but not for the internal Logistic Regression Classifier because this LRC already return normalized results between 0 and 1. The Bayes Classifier result is not classified because of this, and because to be honest the Bayes Classification offers the worst results acording to the benchmarks, while neural network gives great scores.

But you can normalize the results using the normalizeNeural function, and the distribution of values will be between 0 and 1.